# Use invert in an object with many entries

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to reverse the keys/values.

So , I am trying something like:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var myObj = [

    {'name': 'Mike', 'number' : 'b1' , 'level' : 0 },
    {'name': 'Tom', 'number' : 'b2' , 'level' : 0 }
];


Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(k) { 
    _.invert(myObj[k]);
});



console.log(myObj);
```

So, I want to receive:

```
{'Mike': 'name', 'b1' : 'number' , '0' : level },
{'Tom': 'name', 'b2' : 'number' , '0' : level }
```

But the above gives me again the initial object.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this in the first place? Also what if 2 values are the same? Note that `myObj` is array and Object.keys is for objects

Comment: @charlietfl:There is a reason for this.:)The values will never be the same.

Comment: @charlietfl I think the fact that lodash and underscore offer an `invert()` method is a reasonable indication that the functionality is sometimes useful. I've used it in the past, although I can't recall the exact context in which I found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var result = _.map(myObj, _.invert);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash **[`_.invert`](https://lodash.com/docs#invert)** just return a new inverted object, so you need to update the array element with returned object. Also there is no need for **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, since it's an array **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** is enough.

```js
var myObj = [

  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'number': 'b1',
    'level': 0
  }, {
    'name': 'Tom',
    'number': 'b2',
    'level': 0
  }
];

myObj.forEach(function(v, k) {
  myObj[k] = _.invert(v);
});



console.log(myObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to generate new inverted array then use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method.

```
var res = myObj.map(_.invert);
```

```js
var myObj = [

  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'number': 'b1',
    'level': 0
  }, {
    'name': 'Tom',
    'number': 'b2',
    'level': 0
  }
];

var res = myObj.map(_.invert);



console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.invert()` doesn't alter the input object. Here's what you need:

```
var myObj = [
    {'name': 'Mike', 'number' : 'b1' , 'level' : 0 },
    {'name': 'Tom', 'number' : 'b2' , 'level' : 0 }
];

// ES6 one-liners with arrow function
// with array input
var invertedObj = myObj.map(k => { _.invert(myObj[k]) });
// with object input
var invertedObj = Object.keys(myObj).map(k => { _.invert(myObj[k]) });

// ES5
// with array input
var invertedObj = myObj.map(function(k) { 
  return _.invert(myObj[k]);
});
// with object  input
var invertedObj = Object.keys(myObj).map(function(k) { 
  return _.invert(myObj[k]);
});
```

Comment: `Object.keys` isn't intended for arrays either

Comment: In ES6, a non object argument will be coerced to an object. If the asker is truly working with arrays, however, `Object.keys()` is certainly not necessary.

Comment: regardless of coercion or not...myObj is clearly array as shown. Just unorthodox regardless if it works or not

Comment: Yes, it is an array, and it will be coerced into an object in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `myObj` is an array, not an object so there is no need to perform `Object.keys()` on it.

```
var array = [
    {'name': 'Mike', 'number' : 'b1' , 'level' : 0 },
    {'name': 'Tom', 'number' : 'b2' , 'level' : 0 }
];

var myNewArray = array.map(object => {
    var box = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        box[object[key]] = key;
    });
    return box;
});
```